# UIKit keys missing in info.plist file

Tags: iphone, uikit

I want to add UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key in info.plist file

but all the UI related keys are missing.

What should be done to get UI related keys in info.plist file

I have default frameworks uikit, foundation and coregraphics added to my project.

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the project.xcodeproj file, search for Info.plist.  The entry is probably missing this:

plistStructureDefinitionIdentifier = "com.apple.xcode.plist.structure-definition.iphone.info-plist";

Comment: Kudos to you, couldn't find any info on  "plistStructureDefinitionIdentifier", but it works. For anyone else: The file is located WITHIN the .xcodeproj file and is named "project.pbxproj". The final line should look like this: 8D1107310486CEB800E47090 /* Info.plist */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.xml; path = Info.plist; plistStructureDefinitionIdentifier = "com.apple.xcode.plist.structure-definition.iphone.info-plist"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };

Comment: If following the above comment: search for every instance of "plist" while you're editing the file, because if it already exists, you might have to replace with "8D1107310486CEB800E47090" elsewhere too. Also, you might need a "name = Info.plist" in there, depending on your directory structure.  ...or...
Better yet, simply insert Seth's suggested "plistStructureDefinitionIdentifier = ..." into the existing Info.plist entry, in the position indicated by marimba's comment.  Got it?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your project for an earlier iOS version, it is still made for this and doesn't recognize the new keys.
Try this: Open your Info.plist as a plain text file and insert following text to it.

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

Save the file and any the app closes now on suspend.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply, but the problem is not only the above key is invisible but also all ui related keys are not there eg: UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. :(